# How i search data in different tables in laravel?

Tags: laravel, search

I am new to laravel i am trying to search data in my tables inside database.

> This is my route code

```
Route::get('/search','StudentController@search');
Route::get('/search','ProfessorController@search');
```

> This is the search function code for professor

```
  public function search(Request $request)
    {   
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $professors = DB::table('professors')->where('name', 'like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(4);
        return view('professor.index', ['professors' => $professors]);  
    }
```

> and this is the search function code for students

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {   
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $students = DB::table('students')->where('lastname', 'like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(4);
        return view('student.index', ['students' => $students]);  
    }
```

> This is the view code for professor

```
        <form action="/search" method="GET">
                   <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bouton">Search</button>
                        </span>
                   </div>
       </form>
```

> and this is for students

```
 <form action="/search" method="GET">
             <div class="input-group">
               <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
               <span class="input-group-prepend">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bouton">Search</button>
               </span>
            </div>
 </form>
```

Now! the problem that i am having is that when i try to search data in my students  view it takes me to the professors view and when i switch places in route it always execute the lats route !!

> I really how that my issue is clear and i would be very happy if someone helps me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want dynamic result use this approach so that you don't need to create
>   new routes and method every time. Just pass the extra parameter.

Change your routes to

```
Route::get('/search/{model?}','StudentController@search');
```

and forms to

```
<form action="/search/students" method="GET">
<form action="/search/professors" method="GET">
```

and in controller

```
$result = DB::table($request->model)->where('name', 'like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are the same to Laravel. How would it know which one do you want. Slight modification would do.

```
Route::get('/search-students','StudentController@search');
Route::get('/search-professors','ProfessorController@search');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be diffrent with each other routes.

**For student**

```
Route::get('student/search','StudentController@search')->name('student.search');

<form action="{{ route('student.search')}}" method="GET">
</form>
```

**For professor**

```
Route::get('professor/search','ProfessorController@search')->name('professor.search');
<form action="{{ route('professor.search')}}" method="GET">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need if statement like this:

```
 public function index()
 {
    $search = request()->query('search');

    if ($search) {
        $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->simplePaginate(1);
    } else {
        $posts = Post::simplePaginate(3);
    }
    return view('welcome')
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('tags', Tag::all())
        ->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

so, in your code it could be like this:

```
 public function search(Request $request)
{   
    $search = $request->get('search');
    if($search){
    $professors = DB::table('professors')->where('name', 
    'like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(4);
    } else { 
    $professors = Professor::all(); 
    }
     return view('professor.index', ['professors' => 
     $professors]); 


}
```